# Where is the `o:` variable prefix documented?

Tags: neovim

I'm aware of `:help variable-scope`, which describes the following:

```
buffer-variable    b:  Local to the current buffer.
window-variable    w:  Local to the current window.
tabpage-variable   t:  Local to the current tab page.
global-variable    g:  Global.
local-variable     l:  Local to a function.
script-variable    s:  Local to a :source'ed Vim script.
function-argument  a:  Function argument (only inside a function).
vim-variable       v:  Global, predefined by Vim.
```

I learned there are a few more while reading about [lualine](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim):

> Variables from `g:`, `v:`, `t:`, `w:`, `b:`, `o`, `go:`, `vo:`, `to:`, `wo:`, `bo:` scopes can be used.
>
> See `:h lua-vim-variables` and `:h lua-vim-options` if you are not sure what to use.
>
> `sections = { lualine_a = { 'g:coc_status', 'bo:filetype' } }`

But I can't find where `o:`, `go:`, etc. are documented. When I tried `echo o:shiftwidth` vim complained `E121: Undefined variable: o`.

How are these supposed to be used? Is it a lua-only feature, or is it specific to lualine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the lualine readme is stating is that *lualine* supports variables from those scopes. It doesn't mean that n/vim has those variable scopes. n/vim has only the scopes mentioned in `:h variable-scopes` and nvim provides some options, e.g., `:h vim.o`, `:h vim.go`, and `:h vim.bo`, and `:h vim.wo` (see `:h lua-vim-options`).

In [`components/special/vim_var_component.lua`](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim/tree/master/lua/lualine/components/special/vim_var_component.lua#L7-L12), we can see that lualine is using a regex to check for vim variable in a lualine component.

```
function M:update_status()
  local component = self.options[1]
  -- vim variable component
  -- accepts g:, v:, t:, w:, b:, o, go:, vo:, to:, wo:, bo:
  -- filters g portion from g:var
  local scope = component:match('[gvtwb]?o?')
  -- ...
end
```

The regex `[gvtwb]?o?` will match patterns whose:

- first character is:

  - either any of the characters in `[gvtwb]`

    - in which case the next character will be:

      - either `o`
      - or nothing (i.e., a one-character pattern)
  - or an `o` (i.e., a one-character pattern)
  - or nothing (i.e., a zero-character pattern)

If we list them out, we'll see that the patterns meeting the conditions above are the exact patterns mentioned in the lualine readme:

```
g:, v:, t:, w:, b:, o, go:, vo:, to:, wo:, bo:
```

The scopes `vo:` and `to:` aren't supported by n/vim. If we use them in lualine config, n/vim understandably outputs error messages akin to "Attempting to index nil value."

---

**TL;DR**: All those scopes in lualine readme are supported by lualine but not all of those are supported by n/vim.

Comment: I'm not getting something about lualine. How can it "support" variabe scopes which don't exist in the platform it's running in? What am I missing?

Comment: By "lualine supports X" I mean that lualine won't be the barrier in the use of X. Whether X actually exists (assuming X is a variable) is not the point of discussion. Or a more specific way to put this is: if ever nvim decides to add support for `vim.to` options (for tabs, I guess), then the current version of lualine will support that, just because of the way lualine is coded.

Comment: @Rich, I guess, we can raise the point that lualine's readme is wrong, because using scopes like `vim.to` _does_ raise error (as I said in the answer). In that sense it doesn't support those option scopes. But then we're getting into linguistic semantics and I'm not an expert on it.

Comment: See https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim/pull/855.

Answer (score 1):

Those with 'o' correspond to vim options, and these are documented in `:h lua-vim-options`. That is, `o:` corresponds to `vim.o`, `bo:` corresponds to `vim.bo`, and so on.

For example, `bo:filetype` corresponds to `vim.bo.filetype`, and `o:shiftwidth` corresponds to `vim.o.shiftwidth`.

Comment: Yes, but `:h lua-vim-options` doesn't support `vim.vo`, `vim.to`, which lualine readme says it supports.

Comment: `:h lua-vim-options` doesn't mention `o:` anywhere that I can see on nvim 0.7.2.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge maybe I wasn't fully clear, but what I meant was that `o:` in **lualine** corresponds to `vim.o` in `:h lua-vim-options`.